# Question about multivariable critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4 - 4xy + 3$ 
I solved it and I got two minimum points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$
and I got $(0,0)$ as my saddle point 
but I'm suspecting that the function doesn't have a saddle point
are my answers right?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29%3Dx%5E4%2By%5E4%E2%88%924xy%2B3+critical+points&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22critical+points%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22OptimizationWord%22%7D) agrees with your computation (as opposed to your suspicion).

Answer (score 3):

Let be $y=x$ then

$$
g(x) = f(x,x) = - 4x^2 +2x^4 + 3
$$
which has a maximum at $x=0$. Let be $y=-x$, then 
$$
h(x) = f(x, - x) =  4x^2 +2x^4 + 3
$$
which has a minimum at $x=0$. Therefore your function does have a saddle point at $(0,0)$.